# Generated SSRS PDF returning blank when retrieved through Nodejs Express Server

Tags: node.js, pdf, express, reporting-services

Long time reader, first time poster.

I am trying to generate a PDF file from SSRS and serve it to the end user, with a NodeJS server (Express) acting as a service layer in the middle. We don't want to expose anything that pertains to the SSRS to the user, so I have the node server put together the link and make the get request to the server.

The problem is, I can get the PDF through the body of the response from the SSRS and pass it through to the HTML page, but the file is completely blank despite being the proper page count and file size. This happens even when I write the data to a file as a test.

When using POSTMAN or curl in the web browser, or doing a direct GET request from Chrome it loads the file successfully as an attachment and with no body. When I do the same get request through node, however, I get a header that claims there is an attachment along with a body containing the PDF code that I can only imagine that was converted to utf-8 encoding when it hit my node server. Because the report is generated through SSRS, I cannot use express's response.download() or similar functionalists because I do not have an exact path to the PDF before it's generated.

Making things more complex, I have to rely on requests limited to those in the [http-ntlm library](https://github.com/SamDecrock/node-http-ntlm) to get a response from our SSRS server to begin with, so piping and similar methods are unavailable to me to the best of my knowledge. I chose this primarily because it allows me to access the SSRS through http as opposed to https (our SSRS configuration doesn't serve a response to https).

The node server function:

```
exports.getReportPDF = function (req, resp)
{
//-Gets the link info from the client side
var myLink = req.body;
var fileLink = myLink.Data;

httpntlm.post({
    url: fileLink,
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    workstation: 'workstation',
    domain: 'domain'
}, function (err, res){ //-Returns once the stream is complete
    if(err) return err;

    var resBase64 = new Buffer(res.body).toString('base64');
    resp.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
    resp.setHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'base64');

    fs.writeFile("somethingToCheckAgainst.pdf", resBase64, function(writeErr) {
     if(writeErr) {
            console.log(writeErr);
        } else {
            console.log("The file was saved!");
        }
    });
    console.log(resp.get('Content-Disposition'));
    resp.send(resBase64);
});

}
```

Client side function piece:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        var results = xmlhttp.responseText;

        window.open("data:application/pdf;base64, " + results);
    }
}
```

This is a quick and dirty prototype, so I am not concerned about speed and messy code but clean and simple is preferred. How do I get the PDF that is opened in the new window, or the one that is created on the server, to display properly (Not completely blank)? Is this a problem with node interacting with the data from SSRS or is it caused by the way I am handling the data?

Comment: Yeah that library author's choice to use `httpreq` is really confusing. Are you sure you're getting the full document in `res.body`? For example, is `(new Buffer(res.body, 'utf8')).length` a believable size for this PDF?

Comment: Second question, is it necessary in your application to encode the data to base64?

Comment: @AndrewLavers I'm glad I'm not the only one who thinks so! The ntlm threw me for a loop as it was. I'm fairly confident that I am getting the full document in the body... unless the 'http-ntlm' is not returning more than the first chunk. The file size is the same as if I downloaded it using the browser (Chrome) so I assume that everything is there.

Comment: @AndrewLavers To answer your second question: No it is not necessary, it was just something that I tried while looking for a solution. Base64 or no, the result is the same.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem for quite some time.  Trying to be a good citizen and post what solved this for me after several days of troubleshooting since the answer doesn't seem to appear anywhere else on the internet.

In the httpntlm.post, add another option - "binary : true".  If you don't do this, it turns out the response.body is automatically converted to a UTF-8 string which corrupts the PDF and causes it to appear blank.

Answer (score 1):

Even if `http-ntlm` doesn't give you the option to stream it's not necessary to write the data to disk, nor do you need to encode it to base64. You can simply create your own readable stream. Substack's `resumer` npm module makes this nice and clean. Working it into your ntlm callback, it would look something like this:

```
var resumer = require('resumer');

function (err, res){ //-Returns once the stream is complete
    if(err) return next(err);

    var buffer = new Buffer(res.body);
    var stream = resumer().queue(buffer).end();

    resp.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=out.pdf');
    resp.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
    stream
        .pipe(resp)
        .on('error', next);
};
```

Note also that I'm using the third middleware parameter `next` to handle any errors. Simply doing a `if(err) return err;` like you had it won't help much.

Comment: Hmmm... Didn't make a difference, same result so I don't think it's a streaming thing. **Also, I was mistaken before. The size of the streamed file was almost twice the size of the actual, working file. (902k vs 492k)**